# How do you translate "美容的" for food?

Tags: food, adjectives

In Chinese you can use "美容的" to describe certain kinds of food that are said to benefit your looks. I've never heard "cosmetic" use to describe food's effects on a person, only the visual appeal of the food itself, so I'm wondering if there is a more appropriate translation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

美容：make oneself more beautiful
美容的食物：beauty foods, beauty-enhancing foods

I even found this:
营养美容:  nutritional cosmetology

关键是将有助于**美容的食物**放在手边”，他说。
He said, "The key is having **beauty-enhancing foods** at hand."

试试这些家庭常见食物的**美容用途**吧。
Try the **beautifying effect** of these common household foods.

浆果：不同种类的浆果如蓝莓，黑莓，树莓，小红莓以及草莓都是超赞的**美容食物**哦。
Berries: different kinds of berries such as blueberries, blackberries, raspberries, cranberries, as well as strawberries are all super **beauty foods**.

协会有专家为你解答体育按摩、常见病的穴位按摩以及**营养美容**保健等各方面的问题。
Our association has an expert to answer questions on all kinds of problems relating to sports massage, acupuncture point massage for common illnesses as well as **nutritional cosmetology**, health care etcetera.

Answer (score 2):

美容 in 美容食品 is an adjectival noun (beauty) or an adjective (beautifying)

The term 美容食品 (beauty-enhancing food) is relatively new. The traditional term for food that is good for your beauty is 養顔食品.

養顔 can be a verb or an adjective

美容的 in 美容的食品 is an adjective (noun + adjective marker 的) for "beautifying"